# Entity Framework TPH duplicates columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design

So me and my team are developing a wrapper around a REST api returning json values. Since some calls to the API return many values that're pretty consistent we want to cache them in a local database.

Currently we use a TPT database mapping, but this is much slower than TPH. If we switch to TPH though EF duplicates certain columns. Here is our problem:

**Expected TPH mapping**

`+------------------+
 |      Items       |
 +------------------+
 | Suffix           |
 +------------------+
 | SecondarySuffix  |
 +------------------+
 | ItemType         |
 +------------------+`

**What EF actually does**

`+------------------+
 |      Items       |
 +------------------+
 | Suffix           |
 +------------------+
 | SecondarySuffix  |
 +------------------+
 | Suffix1          |
 +------------------+
 | SecondarySuffix1 |
 +------------------+
 | Suffix2          |
 +------------------+
 | SecondarySuffix2 |
 +------------------+
 | Suffix3          |
 +------------------+
 | SecondarySuffix3 |
 +------------------+
 | ItemType         |
 +------------------+`

One of my programmers thinks that this is because 4 classes implement the same interface (`IUpgradable`). Therefore because there is no guarantee that the implementation of class one is compatible with the implementation of the other three classes it duplicates the columns.

He thinks our best shot would be to override this behaviour, but he also notes that this is apparently not possible (or are we wrong).
This said we are currently thinking about adding a common base class to avoid this problem.

Did we miss something crucial, or is this a "flaw" in a TPH approach?

// edit: Since the project is Open sour I'll just link to the files. Everything we currently have should be in the Entities project, and if not the Http branch.
https://gw2dotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GW2.NET-Http/GW2.NET.Entities/

**Inheritance tree that causes EF to create duplicate columns**

```
interface IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

abstract class Item
{
    int ItemType { get; set; }
}

class Armor : Item, IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

class Weapon : Item, IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

class Back : Item, IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

class Trinket : Item, IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}
```

**Inheritance tree that solves the problem by introducing a common ancestor**

```
interface IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

abstract class Item
{
    int ItemType { get; set; }
}

abstract class CombatItem : Item, IUpgradable
{
    int? Suffix { get; set; }
    int? SecondarySuffix { get; set; }
}

class Armor : CombatItem { }

class Weapon : CombatItem { }

class Back : CombatItem { }

class Trinket : CombatItem { }
```

**The question**

For the inheritance tree that causes duplicate columns: instead of adding another level of inheritance, can I force EF to use the same columns across all classes that implement `IUpgradable`?

Comment: Post your entity types, please.

Comment: Whooops. I updated the Original Question

Comment: An interface is not inheritance, so EF will never re-use the columns if you only implement the interface without common ancestor. Why would you want that?

Comment: @GertArnold, I think you missed something: all classes that implement `IUpgradable` have a common ancestor `Item`. Only because `Item` itself is not `IUpgradable`, we get duplicate columns. I'd argue that all implementations of `IUpgradable` in different derived classes of `Item` should still map to the same columns. After all, they have the exact same contract. The solution I came up with was to add another level of inheritance (`CombatItem : Item, IUpgradable`), but only to satisfy EF's weird requirements. The software architect inside me thinks that's complete bullcrap.

Comment: The common ancestor doesn't implement the interface, that's the point. EF is stark blind to the interface of each individual class.